# Is this girl "piling on agony" or " throwing a pity party" or what?

Tags: expressions, idioms

Is this girl"piling on agony"? ( I mean she is trying to draw attentions, while her situation is not that bad and scary, she is shedding fake tears , and reacting so exaggeratedly )

What is the exact idiom or expression for describing such false (?) exaggerated reactions just for gaining others' attentions or sympathy? 
"pile on agony " or "to throw pity party" or " to be drama queen" or what?

http://youtu.be/MZIBz-9J1o4

Comment: 'A pitiable embodiment of histrionics.' Or 'A deplorable manifestation of human melodramacity.'

Comment: Wow! Thanks! Dear  @Kugelblitz! , can you use that in a sentence? For example; about this girl! Actually I'l like to know the "verb"with which that expression might be used. :)

Comment: Verb eh? Let's see...

You can say she's 'being melodramatic', or she 'became overwrought when receiving her flu shot.'

Comment: I see. Thanks! ,  why don't you change your comment into answer so that I can up vote it?!:) @Kugelblitz! :)

Comment: I up voted, but I will wait a little for more answers, if any.:)

Comment: Very sensible!!

Comment: I give another example: http://www.aparat.com/v/C2ixh/ننه_من_غریبم_بازی , in this video some police officers are talking with a driver who has broken some traffic laws, but he all of a sudden throw himself on the ground, and cries and claimes that hasn't done anything wrong and he is not deserved to being punished! Police tells him stop that plying!  @Kugelblitz

Comment: www.http://www.aparat.com/v/C2ixh/ننه_من_غریبم_بازی

Comment: Yea, so exaggerated behaviour, or overreacting, or any of the already mentioned phrases/sentences should be more than enough to efficaciously portray the meaning you wish to spread.

Comment: *stop that playing!

Answer (score 2):

Some ways to put it:

With (quite a bit of) sarcasm:

> Watching her get a flu shot makes me think she's a pitiable embodiment of histrionics.
>
> Watching her get a flu shot makes me think she's a deplorable manifestation 
>       of human melodramatics.

Other (nicer) ways to put it:

> She's being very melodramatic

Below is my preferred sentence:

> She was perpetually overwrought during the course of receiving her flu shot.

Comment: I don't think "melodramacity" or even "melodramaticity" is a word.  An instance of melodrama is "melodramatics."

Comment: I have seen that word in usage, but I believe you're right about it not being officially recognized as a linguistic word/term. Thank you for the heads up.

Comment: I actually like "melodramacity" (mellow-dra-MA-sit-ee) because it looks like Melodrama-city.  I just wouldn't want an English language learner to misunderstand the word play and take it as a word in common use.

Comment: Indeed. It does roll of the tongue smoothly.

Comment: Hey Kugel use `>` to put in quotes.

Comment: +1 for melodramatic. - add the definition?

Comment: Thanks for the tip.

Melodramatic: Exaggeratedly emotional or sentimental.